# xmms2 notification with album art under Awesome

Tags: awesome, xmms2

I have the following in my `.config/awesome/rc.lua`:

```
--{{{ Display noify with current xmms2 playlist
function xmms2()
    local f = io.popen("nyxmms2 status -f '${artist} - ${album} - ${title}'")
    local fr = ""
    for line in f:lines() do
    fr = fr .. line .. '\n'
    end
    f:close()
    naughty.notify({ title = "Currently playing:", text = fr, timeout = 5})
end
--}}}
```

I would like to add album art to this.

Does anyone have an idea of how to do this?

I am looking for something like [this mpd setup](https://github.com/Donearm/Mpd-Info) but for xmms2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `notify-send` for this. It supports the `--icon` switch which points to the pixel graphic to be displayed. Vector graphics don't seem to be supported. This can easily be hooked into the new song event of audio players. I don't know xmms2 so I can't provide details on how to do this. This is all you need for the notifications:

```
notify-send --expire-time=5000 --icon="$ALBUMART" "$ARTIST" "$SONG"
```

This solution works with the awesome WM.

Comment: This is not bad and certainly a good way towards what I want.  Note that `--expire-time` seems to be in ms on my machine.  However, I still would need to find the path for the cover art and download it if it is not present.  I am looking for a full solution -- lazy I know.

Comment: Thanks, I fixed the expire-time. Finding the path is not a window manager problem, it's an issue on it's own. I would place the (not yet written) code in a shell script which can be used with any window manager. Does xmms2 have access to the icon? If yes write it to a tmp file. If not then your question tags don't relate to your problem at all.

Comment: Asked a [separate question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/62242/10526) from your comment above.