# xmms2 cover art

Tags: appearance, xmms2

Does xmms2 have bindings either a Python API or a command line tool to find the album cover art of an MP3?

*Related to [xmms2 notification with album art under Awesome](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/62175/10526).*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a generic way to do that, that involves a single command or function, sorry this isn't it.

Assuming you know the location of the of the covers, for example `~/.xmms2/clients/generic/art/` you just need the name of the file corresponding with a particular `album` and `artist`.

According to the wiki the name of the image file is calculated using the `md5 checksum` of the `"$artist-$album"` all in lowercase, resulting in something like `186bdc073dcbab197caa9000e441a740-thumbnail.jpg` for the album "Some Album" from artist "Some Artist". You can calculate this with a few shell commands.

```
COVER=$(echo "Some Artist-Some Album" | tr [A-Z] [a-z] | md5sum)
COVER="${COVER%  -*}-thumbnail.jpg"
```

You can replace `"Some Artist-Some Album"` with `"$artist-$album"` given the values you need are actually stored on those variables.

Using `${COVER%  -*}` because md5sum adds a `" -"` at the end of the generated string, maybe there is a better way to fix that.